# What is the etymology of the term “Bumfiddler”?

Tags: etymology

I heard about about the term '*bumfiddler*' from a E-Newsletter I receive, and I was wondering the etymology of this term?

Is it a purely sexual phrase, or does it have a more mainstream / normal usage?

[This website](http://www.wordsandphrasesfromthepast.com/blog/bumfiddler) seems to define it as:

> Noun:
>    - A busybody / fidgety person.

Is, *or should I say*, was this a real / used word?

Comment: It's featured in [50 Words That Sound Rude But Actually Aren't](http://mentalfloss.com/article/58036/50-words-sound-rude-actually-arent) *To **bumfiddle** means to pollute or spoil something, in particular by scribbling or drawing on a document to make it invalid. A **bumfiddler** is someone who does precisely that.* Which implies it's not even "rude", let alone "sexual". But [Partridge](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22The+derivative+bum%E2%80%94fiddler%22) has the etymology as a pun on ***ars musica*** (*the musical arts*, I assume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The Gentleman's Magazine Library - Dialect, Proverbs and Word-lore* (edited by George Laurence Gomme) says that *bumfiddle* might be a corruption of the term *bound-bailiff* but doesn't include the source of the corruption:

> The learned author of the " Commentary on the Laws of England" has clearly shown (b. i. c 9, 8vo. edit, p. 346) that another word, to which the same monosyllable is now usually prefixed, has suffered an alteration by the common people; for that " bound-bailiff" was the original term : and possibly this may have been the case in the word before mentioned, though I am not deeply enough versed in antiquarian lore to discover the source of the corruption.

However, according to *OED*, the noun *bumfiddle*, meaning bum, is from 1675 and the noun *bound-bailiff* is from 1768. Thus, the vulgar meaning *bumfiddle* might be earlier than the non-vulgar meaning.

*OED* defines *bound-bailiff* as a name given by Blackstone to the sheriff's officer in explanation of the vulgar term *bumbailiff*:

> The sheriff being answerable for the misdemesnors of these bailiffs, they are therefore usually bound in a bond for the due execution of their office, and thence are called bound-bailiffs.
>
> <sub>1768   W. Blackstone Comm. Laws Eng. I. 346</sub>

OED defines *bumbailiff* as a contemptuous synonym of *bailiff* which means an officer of justice under a sheriff, who executes writs and processes, distrains, and arrests; a warrant officer, pursuivant, or catchpoll.

According to *OED*, the etymology of *bumbaillif* is apparently < bum  + bailiff : i.e. the bailiff that is close at the debtor's back, or that catches him in the rear. Compare the French equivalent *pousse-cul* , colloquially shortened to *cul*, precisely like the English.

The Routledge Dictionary of Historical Slang (by Eric Partridge) says that the derivative *bumfiddler*, meaning a fornicator, is from 17th century and rare. Here is the excerpt of the definition of *bum-fiddle*:

[image]

*A Dictionary of Sexual Language and Imagery in Shakespearean and Stuart Literature* (by Gordon Williams) includes different slang meanings of *bumfiddle* in different works. It says that the term is a slippery one ranging from bum to bumbaste. The term is also used for coital and vaginal sense. You can read further in [Google Books](https://books.google.ca/books?id=2XtWDhgljvkC&pg=PA172&dq=bumfiddle&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ5d2M997JAhWvoYMKHZC4AEMQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=bumfiddle&f=false).

Another similar term is *bumfeagle* which also means *bumbaste*: to beat on the buttocks (*dialectal, England*). [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bumbaste)

Here is the excerpt from *The Routledge Dictionary of Historical Slang*:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

***[Bumfiddler](http://www.definition-of.com/bum+fiddler) :***

> - A lecherous or promiscuous man. See philanderer for synonyms.

The origin is from *bum +fiddle* and its usage appears to be quite old:

***Bumfiddle***:

= ***bum*** n.1 (The buttocks, the part on which we sit; the posteriors)

> - ***1675 Cotton Burlesque in Poet. Wks. (1765) 231*** So her Bum-fiddle I had clapp'd.
> - ***1810 W. Hickey Mem. (1960) xix. 311, I,***  of course, shall pay, and they may kiss my bum fiddle. 1825 H. Wilson Mem. I. 91, I am puzzled to guess..how, you came to shew me, an utter stranger, your bum-fiddle!

also ***bumfiddler***:

> - ***1560 Trag. Rich. II (1870) 4*** 2 To say I will teare this paper..or fowler words than that, as to say I will bumfidle your paper.
> - ***1611 Davies Scourge Folly in Wright Dict. Obs. & Prov. Eng.***, A busie-body hardly she abides; Yet she's well-pleased with all bumfidlers.
> - ***1618 Fletcher Chances i. vi,*** And am I now bumfidl'd with a Bastard?

OED